# How do I make my sprites move (the enemy sprites), by themselves?

Tags: python, pygame

I need to make my enemy sprites defined in drawGrid function move, I would like them to move to the edge of the grid (horizontally) and once reaching the end of the grid, they move down a certain amount and begin moving the opposite horizontal direction. (Like the aliens in space invaders.)

I have tried to move them to no avail.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((650, 630))

pygame.display.set_caption("PeaShooters")

avatar = pygame.image.load('Sprite 1 Red.png')
enemy1 = pygame.image.load('Sprite 3 Red.png')
enemy2 = pygame.image.load('Sprite 3 Yellow.png')
background = pygame.image.load('Bg.jpg')
white = (255, 255, 255)

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, shots):
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 500
        self.width = 40
        self.height = 60
        self.vel = shots


def drawGrid():
    window.blit(background, (0,0))
    window.blit(enemy1, (en.x, en.y))
    window.blit(enemy1, (200, en.y))
    window.blit(enemy1, (100, en.y))
    window.blit(enemy1, (400, en.y))
    window.blit(enemy1, (500, en.y))
    window.blit(enemy1, (en.x, en.y))
    window.blit(enemy2, (50, 200))
    window.blit(enemy2, (150, 200))
    window.blit(enemy2, (250, 200))
    window.blit(enemy2, (350, 200))
    window.blit(enemy2, (450, 200))
    window.blit(enemy2, (530, 200))
    window.blit(avatar, (av.x, av.y))
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,50], [50, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,50], [600, 50], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [600,600], [600, 50], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,600], [600, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,450], [600, 450], 5)

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()


class shots(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, colour):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.colour = colour
        self.vel = shots

    def draw(self, window):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.colour, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)

class enemy(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self. x, self.end]
        self.vel = 4

    def draw(self,window):
        self.move()

    def move(self):
        pass

av = player(300, 500, 40, 60, 9)
en = enemy(300, 100, 40, 60, 500)

bullets = []
running = True
while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.y < 600 and bullet.y > 70:
            bullet.y -= 8
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and av.y > 440:
        av.y -= av.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and av.x > 65:
        av.x -= av.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and av.y < 535:
        av.y += av.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and av.x < 530:
        av.x += av.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(shots(round(av.x + av.width//2), round(av.y + av.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))


    drawGrid()

window.blit(enemy, (en.x, en.y))
window.blit(avatar, (x,y))

pygame.quit()
```

I expect the enemies to move, in the way I have described but they do not move at all.

Comment: Do you update what the values of `en.x` and `en.y` anywhere? I do not see where these would change in your code, and they need to change to get moving enemies from `drawGrid()`

Comment: Would you be able to give me an outline on how I would do this?

Comment: inside `while running:` you have to change enemy position.

Comment: So if I wanted to change it so that the enemy moved right by 50 every 3 seconds and stopped moved down by 30 and moved left when it reached a value of 500. Would I do something like:

Comment: would I use for count?

Comment: you should create many `enemy()` with own position but you have only one `enemy()`  and you blit many images.

Comment: So I should give all the enemies actual values? Instead of coordinates?

Comment: `pygame.time.get_ticks()` gives you time in miliseconds since `pygame.init()` and you can use it to count time between moves.

Comment: So I put pygame.time.get_ticks(3000)?

Comment: you should have `en1 = enemy(...)`, `en2 = enemy(...)`, ...`en12 = enemy(... )` etc. and use it to change position `en1.x += 10`, `en2.x += 10` ... `en12 += 10` and use it to draw `blit(image1, en1.x, en1.y)`, `blit(image1, en2.x, en2.y)`, ... `blit(image2, en12.x, en12.y)`

Comment: So inside the brackets for en1,2,3 etc I have the coordinates?

Comment: in enemy you can set `next_move = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000` and in every loop you get `current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()` and check `if current_time >= next_move: do_move(); next_move = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000`

Comment: you created `class enemy(object):  def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):` so you have position and size in every `enemy(...)`

Comment: Sorry that I keep asking questions, so what I need to do is define each one of the sprites as I have defined en.x, en.y etcetera?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things I would do to get yourself closer to the game you are looking for:

1. Create more enemy objects

Right now you create 1 enemy here: `en = enemy(300, 100, 40, 60, 500)` and just throw enemy images at the screen in a bunch of places.  To really make use of the `Enemy` class, I would do something like this:

```
enemiesList = []
for i in range (MAX_ENEMIES_I_WANT):
    enemiesList.append(enemy(300, 100*i, 40, 60, 500))
```

Note: you will need to define where you place your enemies differently if you want them to fall into a certain shape.  For the traditional space invaders you can loop twice, once for y coordinates, once for x.

2. blit your enemies from within your Enemy class

Instead of doing things the way you have them now, I would add a `blitToScreen()` method in your Enemy class.  Something like:

```
def BlitToScreen(self,screen):
    screen.blit(self.sprite, self.x, self.y)
```

Then, blitting all of your enemies to screen becomes two lines:

```
for e in enemiesList:
    e.BlitToScreen(window)
```

3. Finally getting to your question, if we are truly mimicking space invaders, each enemy moves the exact same amount each frame so we can make the same changes to each Enemy object.

If you have a `frame` number it will look something like this:

```
tomove = [0,0]
if(frame%100 == 99):
    tomove[0] += 50 # Move down
else if(frame/100%2 == 0):
    tomove[1] +=50 # Move right
else:
    tomove[1] -=50 # Move left

for e in enemies:
    e.x += tomove[0]
    e.y += tomove[1]
```

Hopefully this is helpful for you!

Answer (score 1):

@Hoog's answer mostly covers the basics of what's wrong with the OP's code, and how to get it working.

However the OP *really* should consider using the [PyGame sprite class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) for each "enemy" object (well, all objects actually).  *Yes*, it's a bit more work to setup initially, but it provides so much extra (pre-optimised) functionality that you would otherwise have to code.  This takes some of the tedious work out of the programming, and allows you to spend more time coding up an interesting game.

It's fairly trivial to convert the existing objects to Sprites:

```
class Enemy( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, bitmap, x, y, end=None ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image  = bitmap
        self.rect   = bitmap.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.vel    = 4
        self.end    = end

   def update():
       # TODO - handle any sort of sprite movement
```

Create a bunch of sprites, as per @Hoog's suggestion, except use a Sprite Group to hold them:

```
enemy_image1 = pygame.image.load('Sprite 3 Red.png')
enemy_image2 = pygame.image.load('Sprite 3 Yellow.png')

...

enemies_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
for j in range( ENEMY_LINE_COUNT ):
    for i in range( ENEMY_PER_LINE_COUNT ):
         enemy_x = 50 + ( i * 30 )
         enemy_y = 50 + ( j * 40 )
         enemies_list.append( Enemy( enemy_image1, enemy_x, enemy_y ) )
```

The Moving and Drawing can then be handled easily in your main loop, using the abilities (and ease) of the Sprite Group:

```
while running:
    ...
    enemies_list.update()        # re-position the sprites
    enemies_list.draw( window )  # draw the entire sprite-group to the window
    ...
```

The Sprite Group `.update()` call (in the main loop) will call the `Enemy.update()` function for every sprite contained in the group.

This brings us to the movement part of your question.  Let's think about how [Space Invaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders) move - Right to Left, Down, Left to Right, Down, More Speed, *repeat* ...  This kind of sounds like a program to me ;)

So I propose to control movement, write a program that each invader follows:

```
# In Enemy.__init__() ~
self.move_program = 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrdllllllllllllds'  #TODO - make better
self.move_cursor  = 0
```

Where each letter of the `self.move_program` effects the movement at each 'tick'.  This leads us to the sprite's `.update()` function:

```
# In Enemy class ~
def update( self ):
    move_instruction = self.move_program[ self.move_cursor ]
    self.move_cursor += 1
    # If the movement program has ended, restart
    if ( self.move_cursor == len( self.move_program ) ):
        self.move_cursor = 0
    # Interpret the movement instruction
    if ( instruction == 'r' ):   # right
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + 10
    elif ( instruction == 'l' ): # left
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x - 10
    elif ( instruction == 'd' ): # down
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + 10
    elif ( instruction == 's' ): # speedup
        self.vel += 1
```

Obviously you can have any sort of instructions you like.  Different sets of instructions could be given to different sprites as part of the constructor.

Putting the game projectiles and player(s) into sprites will allow the code to easily find collisions, etc. but that's another answer.

Comment: So Kingsley just for confirmation, does the enemies_list part of the code (second section you posted) go inside the TODO function?

Comment: No, the enemies list would be declared somewhere before your main event-handling  loop, as it holds all the Invader Sprites for the whole "level".  During the main loop the `update()` and `draw(...)` functions are called.